# JQUERY TAGIT validate if input is numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery TagIt.
I know how to validate an input with javascript using if and isNaN.
However, I'd be grateful if someone showed me how to validate an input tag
and remove it if it is not numeric:

Following code does not work for me 
(still accepting alphanumeric instead of only numeric):

```
    var $tagInp13 = $("#oneSessionInstanceDetails");
        $tagInp13.tagit({
            allowSpaces: true,
            fieldName: "oneSessionInstanceDetails[]",
            preprocessTag: function (val) {
                if (!val) {
                    return '';
                }
                var values = val.split(/[\s,;]+/);
                //var values = val.split(",");//.split(";");
                if (values.length > 1) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        $tagInp13.tagit("createTag", values[i]);
                    }
                    return ''
                } else {
                    return val
                }
            },
/* remove the tag if it is not numeric*/

            tagsChanged: function(tagValue, action, element){
                if (action == 'added'){
                    if (isNaN(tagValue)){
                        $tagInp13.tagit("remove", 'tag', tagValue);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.isNumeric( "-10" )
```

returns true.

From https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/

Comment: thanks, but it does not work when added to TagIt object

Comment: if(!$.isNumeric("10")){remove} should work! "Debug" with console.log($.isNumeric( tagValue ))

Comment: I have tried with filtering the input Array (values_pre), and assigning only numeric vals to the actual tag Array (values), but it still allows alphanumeric input...
var values_pre = val.split(/[\s,;]+/);
    var values = [];
    values_pre.forEach(function(val){
     if ($.isNumeric(val)) values.push(val)
      });

Comment: found my problem - a typo in the <label> name. 
Your method works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this, with afterTagAdded validation:

```
var $tagInp13 = $("#oneSessionInstanceDetails");
    instanceNumbers =  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];
    $tagInp13.tagit({
        allowSpaces: true,
        onlyAvailableTags: true,
        autocomplete: {delay: 0,minLength: 0},
        availableTags: instanceNumbers,
        afterTagAdded: function (event, ui) {
            if ($.inArray(ui.tagLabel, instanceNumbers) == -1) {
                $("#oneSessionInstanceDetails").tagit("removeTagByLabel", ui.tagLabel);
            }
        },
        fieldName: "oneSessionInstanceDetails[]",
        preprocessTag: function (val) {
            if (!val) {
                return '';
            }
            var values = val.split(/[\s,;]+/);
            //var values = val.split(",");//.split(";");
            if (values.length > 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    $tagInp13.tagit("createTag", values[i]);
                }
                return ''
            } else {
                return val
            }
        }
    });
```